# installing tflite_model_maker (TensorFlow Python) Fails

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation, model

So, about a year ago i was developing a tensorflow project and just recently tried to pick it back up, tring to reinstall the tflite_model_maker package always fails.

any help or insight would be grateful.

things i have tried:

- Reinstalling Python10 / pip
- uninstalling python10 to install python11
- uninstalling every thing and install the versions i used a year ago.

nothing has worked.

Either it says

- "INFO: This is taking longer than usual."
- could not find version
- no supported wheel.

Comment: Hi Ashton, welcome to StackOverflow! Are you using conda or pip to install the package? Are you sure you used Python3.10 last year when you worked on the project, might be you were using an earlier version of Python for which this module exists.

Comment: Hi Ashton! I guess you are trying to install lite model maker on raspberry pi or a microcontroller where it might not be supported. I would suggest you to do the training through lite model maker in Colab or local machine with GPU then do the inference using [TFlite runtime](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python) [interpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Here's how I made it work.

- Make sure to use Python 3.9.16 (Ref [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57086#issuecomment-1318418096))
- pip install "setuptools<58.0.0" (If you are using anaconda)
- pip install tflite-model-maker (for me 0.4.2 is the latest)
- pip install numpy==1.23.5 (to fix : `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'`)